# Unexpected request: GET followed by [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress. Angularjs and Karma

Tags: angularjs

spec file

```
'use strict';

describe('component test : home', function () {

    // add module reference you want to test
    beforeEach(module('homeView'));

    // add templates [from karma]
    beforeEach(module('templates'));

    var element;
    var scope;
    var $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile, _$httpBackend_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        element = angular.element('<home-view></home-view>');
        scope.$apply(function () {
            $compile(element)(scope);
        });
    }));


    it('extra column http get', function () {
        var mockResponse = {
            data: {
                success: true,
                message: ':D :D'
            }
        };

        $httpBackend.expectGET('http://localhost:51275/api/ExtraColumn')
            .respond(mockResponse);

        expect(data).toEqual(mockResponse);

        $httpBackend.flush();
    });


    //it('header text', function () {
    //    var title = element.find('h1');
    //    console.log(title.text());
    //    expect(title.text()).toContain('Interviewees');
    //});



});
```

error

```
 Error: Unexpected request: GET http://localhost:51275/api/ExtraColumn
        No more request expected
            at createFatalError (Scripts/angular-mocks.js:1569:19)
            at $httpBackend (Scripts/angular-mocks.js:1616:11)
            at sendReq (Scripts/angular.js:13257:9)
            at serverRequest (Scripts/angular.js:12998:16)
            at processQueue (Scripts/angular.js:17914:37)
            at Scripts/angular.js:17962:27
            at Scope.$digest (Scripts/angular.js:19075:15)
            at ChildScope.$apply (Scripts/angular.js:19463:24)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (home-view/home-view.component.spec.js:19:15)
            at Object.invoke (Scripts/angular.js:5122:19)
            at <Jasmine>
            at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (Scripts/angular-mocks.js:3422:25)
            at Suite.<anonymous> (home-view/home-view.component.spec.js:15:16)
            at <Jasmine>
            at home-view/home-view.component.spec.js:3:1
        ReferenceError: data is not defined
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (home-view/home-view.component.spec.js:36:16)
            at <Jasmine>
```

I am trying to write tests for my angularjs application. The test needs to mock a http request an I wrote this one above and got these error. unexpected get and `$digest` already in progress errors when I do not even have a `$digest` in my code. How do I fix this please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

At any point in time there can be only one `$digest` or $apply operation in progress. This is to prevent very hard to detect bugs from entering your application. The stack trace of this error allows you to trace the origin of the currently executing `$apply` or `$digest` call, which caused the error.

[please refer this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog)